# Can a debt discharged in a bankruptcy be assigned to a different person?

Tags: debt, bankruptcy

I'm in the USA. I took over an apartment lease from someone for the last 4 months of the lease, which ended in May. I've been remaining in the apartment, and have had trouble paying rent.

I am now filing for bankruptcy, but the landlord and former lease holder are acting like I am still accountable to the former lease holder (which may be the case).

My question is if I add my rent to my debt when filing for bankruptct, and if it gets discharged, would that prevent the landlord from going after the lease holder for it?

Or more generally, if a debt is discharged, can the creditor seek that same debt from a different party?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to help the question: In the scenario you describe, you have said the lease ended.  Under what theory would the original lessee be on the hook for anything after the end of the lease?

Comment: @feetwet The back rent might extend into the lease period.

Comment: @feetwet I'm unsure, but the lease holder and landlord seem to be acting as though that is the case. Possibly the landlord is still holding the lease holder accountable for my staying?

Comment: Please [take the Law.SE tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) and note that *you cannot get legal advice here*.

Comment: @feetwet I'm not asking for legal advice specific to my case, and if it seems that way it's a mistake on my part. I want to know if once a debt is discharged for an individual, if a creditor can still pursue it from another individual - I'm, not asking for advice specific to my situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you sublet the apartment from the tenant, that is an agreement between you and the tenant. It may be that the landlord has to approve any subleasing, but the original obligation remains. Therefore even if you have been paying the rent, it is essentially paying on behalf of the tenant (in exchange for you getting the use of the unit). If you don't pay what you owe, the landlord will go after the legal tenant. You have no obligation (debt) to the landlord, you have an obligation to the tenant. The tenant has a debt to the landlord.

If the (remainder of the) lease was assigned to you, that's a contract between you and the landlord, and the original tenant may be out of the picture. Or not: you have to look at the agreement. There could be a clause holding the original tenant financially responsible for your default. Or a clause saying that the original tenant is *not* responsible. If there is no specific statement about that in the agreement, it would depend on state law whether the original tenant is held liable. It would be useful if you clarified whether you have an unpaid obligation from the time of the original lease.

Comment: I'm in NY state. The lease ended but I have remained in the apartment. Someone told me that since the lease ended I'm now in an implied month to month agreement with the landlord so the original lease holder is irrelevant, but I'm unsure. For the duration of the lease all rent was paid without issue.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if I add my rent to my debt when filing for bankruptct,
> and if it gets discharged, would that prevent the landlord from going
> after the lease holder for it?

Yes. Although it wouldn't prevent you from being evicted after the automatic stay in bankruptcy expires. Lease in force when a bankruptcy petition is filed must either be affirmed and paid in full by the bankrupt, or rejected and turned into unsecured debt (in which case the bankruptcy stay against evicting the tenant ends).

> Or more generally, if a debt is discharged, can the creditor seek that
> same debt from a different party?

If anyone other than the bankrupt has responsibility on a lease, such as a lease guarantor, or an original leaseholder when a lease is subleased, that person's debt is not discharged in bankruptcy.

So, the person whose lease you took over is still on the hook for the amount owed under the lease.

Comment: The lease ended and the other person has moved out, so I would be hoping it would have nothing to do with them. I guess it depends on the lease itself.

Comment: @JasonFriedman The other person is on the hook unless the landlord expressly released them.

Comment: @I was also told that since the lease ended I am on an implied month-month agreement with the landlord and that the original lease holder should be irrelevant.

Comment: @JasonFriedman This is probably not true. The lease generally has provisions governing holdover tenants that keep most provisions of the lease in force.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I guess it all depends on the lease. I will try and get a copy.